# rails 3 spawn alternative in rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

what is the best alternative for spawn in Rails 3?

I need to process ~ 54.000 entries in my DB and search for them amongst a large number of documents in a rake task, I would like to use something like spawn but it's not supported in rails 3 http://railsplugins.org/plugins/433-spawn?criterion_id=1

what is the best alternative?

*** UPDATE ***
I just tried the gem suggested:

```
gem "spawn", :git => 'git://github.com/rfc2822/spawn'
```

in my gem file and then ran bundle install, then I added the following into my rake task:

```
groups.each do |group|
  spawn do
    p group
  end
end
```

but I get undefined method `spawn' for main:Object and I have tried

> require 'spawn'

and without.

Answer (score 3):

Your linked `spawn` is a different `spawn` plugin (read the description). That [fork of spawn](https://github.com/rfc2822/spawn) should work.

Comment: According to the documentation the command is called `spawn_block`. But if you are running this from a rake task, why do you even need that plugin? 54.000 forks/processes will crush your machine.

Comment: it's not 54.000 forks, it's 54.000 entries divided into 7 groups.

Comment: It's still a valid point about the rake task.  What's the point of forking inside a rake task?  Normally you would use spawn to avoid browser timeouts, but in rake you're not under time pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Popular alternatives are [delayed_jobs](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). Both require a bit more setup but offer way more possibilities then spawn

However the rfc2822 fork of spawn actually does work with Rails 3.0.10
Be sure you use `spawn_block` instead of just `spawn`